# Sampling a Chebyshev polynomial with the discrete cosine transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing, interpolation, approximation-theory, chebyshev-polynomials

I have a Chebyshev polynomial $f$ of degree $n$
in point-value form
\begin{align}
f&=:S = \left( \left( x_i, y_i \right) \right)_{i=0}^n, \tag{1} \\
x_i &= \cos\left( \frac{i \pi}{n} \right), i=0, \ldots, n. \tag{2}
\end{align}

I want to sample this polynomial at a higher number of chebyshev points $m$,
with $m>n$, so as to obtain the sample
\begin{align}
S' &= \left( \left( x'_i, y'_i \right) \right)_{i=0}^m, \tag{3} \\
x'_i &= \cos\left( \frac{i \pi}{m} \right), i=0, \ldots, m. \tag{4}
\end{align}
I do this with the Discrete Cosine Transform (DCT).
But no matter what I try I don't get a consistent sample $S'$.
For example, I should get that
$$
y'_0 = y_0 \text{ and } y'_m = y_n, \tag{5}
$$
but I don't.

I will describe my procedure for obtaining $S'$ below.
If you can spot any error, it will be great.
I probably have some constant wrong in the DCT.

**Sampling Procedure**
1. Obtain the coefficient representation of $f$
$$
f\left(x\right) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k \cos\left( k \arccos\left(x\right) \right). \tag{6}
$$
This is done by applying the DCT, so that
$$
a_k = \frac{1}{n} y_0 + \frac{1}{n} y_n \cos\left(k\pi\right) + \frac{2}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} y_i \cos\left(k\frac{i\pi}{n}\right). \tag{7}
$$

2. Form a new set of coefficient $a'_k$ by zero-padding the previously obtained
   coefficient
   $$
   a'_k = \begin{cases}
    a_k & k \le n, \\
    0 & n < k \le m. 
   \end{cases} \tag{8}
   $$
3. Obtain the desired sample $S'$ by applying the DCT to the $a'_k$
   $$
   y'_i = \frac12 a'_0 + \frac12 a'_m \cos\left(i\pi\right) + \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} a'_k \cos\left(i\frac{k\pi}{m}\right). \tag{9}
   $$

Comment: I've never upsampled with the DCT, but if it's anything like using the FFT, then your zeropadding is wrong. Because of the ordering and wrap-around of the frequencies, you can't just concatenate zeros onto the end. You either have to insert the zeros into the middle of the vector or first swap the vector and then zeropad on the edges. Essentially, you just have to make sure the zeros are being put at the higher frequencies.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 Can you say how I should zero-pad $a=[1,2,3]$ with three zeros? Do you mean that it should become either $[0,0,0,1,2,3]$ or $[1,2, 0, 0, 0, 3]$?

Comment: For a 3-element FFT the frequencies are $[0,1/3,-1/3]$. For 6-element FFT we have $[0,1/6,2/6,-3/6,-2/6,-1/6]$. In order to upsample we put zeros in the higher frequencies, which gives $[1,2,0,0,0,3]$.  It makes intuitive sense: what was sampled at $1/3$ is now sampled at $1/6$, you just have to pay attention to where the frequency sample is located. If you just tacked on the zeros to the end, what was sampled at $-1/3$ would then sampled at $+1/3$, which is erroneous. Again, this is for the FFT. I suspect the DCT is similar, but honestly I haven't used the DCT since undergrad course work.